# How to use *NgIf Else on <li> tag

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

How can i correct this code ...

```
  <li title="Login" [hidden]="currentUser.connected"><a routerLink="/login">
      <i class="fa fa-lock"></i> <span>Login</span></a>
  </li>

  <li title="Registration" [hidden]="currentUser.connected"><a routerLink="/register">
     <i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i> <span>Registration</span></a>
  </li>

  <li title="Edit Profile"[hidden]="!currentUser.connected"><a routerLink="/edit-profile">
    <i class="fa fa-id-card-o"></i> <span>Edit Profile</span></a>
  </li>
 
  <li>
  <div *ngIf="brandName == 'MONTER Shipping Line';then ctactive else ctdeactive">
    <ng-template #ctactive>
      <li title="Container Tracking" [hidden]="!currentUser.connected">
        <a routerLink="/tracking"><i class="fa fa-truck"></i> <span>Container Tracking</span></a>
      </li>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template #ctdeactive>
      <li title="Container Tracking">
        <a routerLink="/tracking"><i class="fa fa-truck"></i> <span>Container Tracking</span></a>
      </li>
    </ng-template>
  </div>
  </li>
```

This is an list that i used in my code and i have to hide specific

based on the conditions . By using  it can done .

Comment: Can you elaborate your requirement a bit more? Its hard to understand your question?

Comment: I need to display <li> tag based on  the condition

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is what you meant!

```
  <li title="Container Tracking" [hidden]="!currentUser.connected" *ngIf="brandName == 'MONTER Shipping Line';then ctactive else ctdeactive">
    <ng-template #ctactive>
      <a routerLink="/tracking"><i class="fa fa-truck"></i> <span>Container Tracking</span></a>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template #ctdeactive>
        <a routerLink="/tracking"><i class="fa fa-truck"></i> <span>Container Tracking</span></a>
    </ng-template>
  </li>
```

UPDATE 1:

```
 <ng-container *ngIf="!currentUser.connected">
     <li title="Container Tracking" *ngIf="brandName == 'MONTER Shipping Line';then ctactive else ctdeactive">
    <ng-template #ctactive>
      <a routerLink="/tracking"><i class="fa fa-truck"></i> 
      <span>Container Tracking</span></a>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template #ctdeactive>
        <a routerLink="/tracking"><i class="fa fa-truck"></i> 
        <span>Container Tracking</span></a>
    </ng-template>
  </li>
 </ng-container>
```

Comment: No .Actually what I want is ngIf="brandeName= ''MONTER Shipping Line"  then [hidden]="!currentUser.connected"   else no hidden attribute is needed

Comment: ngIf = '' brandName = " MONTER Shipping Line " ''  then <li> must be like
 <li title="Container Tracking" [hidden]="!currentUser.connected"><a routerLink="/tracking"><i class="fa fa-truck"></i> <span>Container Tracking</span></a></li>                                                                                                                                       <li title="Container Tracking"> <a routerLink="/tracking"> <i class="fa fa-truck"></i> <span>Container Tracking</span></a>
 </li>

Comment: Check update 1, I hope thats what you meant